# Display random array properties in for loop

Tags: javascript, random

I have `for` loop that `alerts` strings from `array`, I wonder how can I `alert` them `randomly`, so it will run `gamesNames.length` times and display them in different-random order each time (without duplicating them) in JavaScript ?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < gamesNames.length; i++) {
            alert (gamesNames[i].Name + gamesNames[i].year );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a Link http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml to the main idea, in Javascript

and here is the Code

```
...
gamesNames.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()}) ;
for (var i = 0; i < gamesNames.length; i++) {
      alert (gamesNames[i].Name + gamesNames[i].year );
}
...
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with items that contain an index and a random number. Shuffle them by sorting on the random number, and use the index to alert the items:

```
var idx = [];
for (var i = 0; i < gamesNames.length; i++) {
  idx.push({ idx: i, rnd: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) });
}
idx.sort(function(x,y){ return x.rnd - y.rnd; });
for (var i = 0; i < idx.length; i++) {
  var j = idx[i].idx;
  alert (gamesNames[j].Name + gamesNames[j].year);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while-loop` for this easily, in combination with [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
while(array.length > 0)
{
    // Get a random index
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    // Append it to the DOM (or do whatever you want with it)
    $("body").append($("<p />").html(array[index]));
    // Remove it from the array
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/spL9M/)